# Permutations/Integer Solutions to Equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm pretty lost on this so I'd appreciate some feedback as to whether or not I'm on the right track.

Find the number of integer solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 15$ subject to the conditions $0 \le x_1 \le 6$, $x_2 \ge 0$, and $x_3 \ge 0$.

Based on other info I've been able to find here, I think this is one way to approach this:

$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 12$ where $y_1 = (x_1 - 1)$, $y_2 = (x_2 - 1)$ and $y_3 = (x_3 - 1)$ with restriction $y_1 \gt 6$.

So now, $(y_1 - 6) + y_2 + y_3 = 12 - 6 = 6$

Which now gives us $C(6 + 3 - 2, 3 - 1) = C(8,2) = 28$

Is this even remotely correct or am I completely missing the boat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t want to replace the variables $x_1,x_2$, and $x_3$ by $y_1,y_2$, and $y_3$: you would do that if your conditions included the inequalities $x_1\ge 1$, $x_2\ge 1$, and $x_3\ge 1$. It’s very specifically a trick to make $0$ the lower bound on all of the variables, and you already have that. Thus, without the restriction that $x_1\le 6$ you get

$$\binom{15+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{17}2\tag{1}$$

solutions in non-negative integers to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=15$.

However, some of these will have $x_1>6$; you want to count those and subtract them from $(1)$. This means counting the solutions in which $x_1\ge 7$, so count non-negative integer solutions to

$$(x_1-7)+x_2+x_3=15-7\;,$$

In other words, count non-negative integer solutions to $y_1+y_2+y_3=8$, and subtract those from $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you Brian; so, if I understand you correctly, I'd end up with $\binom{15+3-1}{3-1} - \binom{8+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{17}2 - \binom{10}2$. Is that correct?

Comment: @jerc: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

You have used a "Stars and Bars" approach. For division of $15$ into $3$ parts, this is perhaps more elaborate than necessary.

If $x_1=0$, the number of possible pairs $(x_2,x_3)$ is $16$, since $x_2$ can take on any value from $0$ to $15$, and then $x_3$ is determined.

If $x_1=1$, the number of possible pairs $(x_2,x_3)$ is $15$.

Continue. If $x_1=6$, the number of possible pairs $(x_2,x_3)$ is $10$.

That gives a total of $16+15+\cdots +10$. This is an arithmetic progression, $7$ terms which average to $13$, so the sum is $91$.